# How to vwait for 2 variables

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

My goal is to do something like this (simplified) code:

```
package require MyProcessor 0.1
package require Tk

proc Open_file {} {
    MyProcessor::Process
}
# Upper frame
frame .top
# Input file name
set inp_file_name "Input file name (press button -->)"
label .top.lbInpFileName
button .top.btInpFile -text "..." -command Open_file
grid .top.lbInpFileName .top.btInpFile
# Two edits
text .inpTxt
text .outTxt
grid .inpTxt
grid .outTxt

vwait ::MyProcessor::inp_file_name
vwait ::MyProcessor::lines
```

And in myprocessor.tcl

```
proc Process {} {
    set inp_file_name [[tk_getOpenFile -initialdir "./"]
    read_lines
    set lines [Proceed $inp_lines]
}
```

While processing variables inp_file_name and lines are changing and I want to display those changes in widgets. What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working prototype of your example above. The key issue you were having is that the label did not have its `-textvariable` attribute set to the `inp_file_name` global variable. The lines of text are inserted into the text widget within the MyProcessor::Process procedure.

```
namespace eval MyProcessor {

    proc Process {} {
        set file_name [tk_getOpenFile -initialdir "./"]
        set h [open $file_name r]
        set lines [read $h]
        .inpTxt insert end $lines
        close $h
        return $file_name
    }
}

proc Open_file {} {
    global inp_file_name
    set inp_file_name [MyProcessor::Process]
}
# Upper frame
frame .top
grid .top
# Input file name
set inp_file_name "Input file name (press button -->)"

# Set the textvariable attribute to the global inp_file_name variable.
label .top.lbInpFileName -textvariable inp_file_name
button .top.btInpFile -text "..." -command Open_file
grid .top.lbInpFileName .top.btInpFile
# Two edits
text .inpTxt
text .outTxt
grid .inpTxt
grid .outTxt
```

Comment: I tried to separate GUI from processing, (placing processing to module in file myprocessor.tcl), so I search for the the way look at the state of variable in module.